# ASP.NET MVC project rebuilt whenever CSHTML changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a big ASP.NET MVC project. Every time I change something in a CSHTML file, the local project is rebuilt. This destroys my session and cache.

I have no idea why VS started to behave that way, but it means a lot of wasting time for me.

The csproj has nothing to force compiling Razor views,  is false and there is nothing in the project file to change its value.

This happens with both IIS and IIS Express.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: To be exact: the DLL of the project is not really built on modifying a Razor view when using IIS Express, but my cache and session are reset anyway.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1875933.aspx?Session+resets+when+saving+CSHTML+file

Comment: One more thing... I put Session_OnEnd() in Global.asax.cs. Session is ended as soon as I save changes to any CSHTML file.

Comment: Something is causing the AppPool to recycle. I've never had this happen for a simple view edit, but modifying CSS/JS will often recycle the AppPool if the files are part of your bundles. Regardless, the only foolproof way to prevent your session/cache being trashed randomly is to get them out of the process. In other words, use State Server/SQL for your session and Redis or something similar for your cache. You can also use Redis for session state as well, so that could be a two-birds thing.